# A question of the topic trigonometry.

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve for $\theta$ the following equation.
>   $$\sqrt {3} \cos \theta - 3 \sin \theta = 4 \sin 2\theta \cos 3\theta.$$

I tried writing sin and cos expansions but it is becoming too long.Please help me.

Comment: If you rewrite this as $f(\theta) = \sqrt3 \cos\theta - 3\sin\theta - 4\sin(2\theta)\cos(3\theta) = 0$ and plot the function $f$ carefully (perhaps using a spreadsheet to help you plot many points), you should find that there are ten different values of $\theta$ in the interval $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$ for which $f(\theta) = 0.$ Do you need to find all ten solutions or is one enough?

Comment: Even if you think your sine and cosine expansions are "too long" you should _show_ them as part of the question. Maybe you were on a good path to a solution and just gave up too early. Or maybe not, but since you are asking other people to help you finish, you should let _them_ decide whether or not to use anything you already did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to solve
$$2\sqrt3\left(\frac{1}{2}\cos\theta-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\sin\theta\right)=4\sin2\theta\cos3\theta$$ or
$$\sqrt3\cos\left(60^{\circ}+\theta\right)+2\sin2\theta\cos(180^{\circ}+3\theta)=0$$ or
$$\sqrt3\cos\left(60^{\circ}+\theta\right)+2\sin2\theta\left(4\cos^3(60^{\circ}+\theta)-3\cos(60^{\circ}+\theta)\right)=0$$ or
$$\cos\left(60^{\circ}+\theta\right)\left(\sqrt3+2\sin2\theta\left(4\cos^2(60^{\circ}+\theta)-3\right)\right)=0,$$
which gives
$$\cos\left(60^{\circ}+\theta\right)=0,$$
which is $\theta=30^{\circ}+180^{\circ}k,$where $k\in\mathbb Z$ or
$$\sqrt3+2\sin2\theta(2+2\cos(120^{\circ}+2\theta)-3)=0$$ or
$$\sqrt3-2\sin2\theta+2(\sin(4\theta+120^{\circ})-\sin120^{\circ})=0$$ or
$$\sin(4\theta+120^{\circ})=\sin2\theta,$$
which gives
$$\theta=-60^{\circ}+180^{\circ}k$$ or
$$\theta=10^{\circ}+60^{\circ}k$$

Comment: could you please give a detailed solution?

Comment: Hello Michael, a Shorter form can be found

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner I think your solution seems shorter because you did not write a full solution.

Comment: @user474243 I wrote a full solution. See now please.

Comment: i didnt understand how you  got cos(60+A)=0 in your first part. Would be very happy if you would elaborte even tht. Thank you!

Comment: @user474243 I used $\cos(a+b)=\cos{a}\cos{b}-\sin{a}\sin{b}$, where $a=60^{\circ}$ and $b=\theta$.

Comment: please elaborate the part from $\sqrt {3} cos (60+\theta)+2sin 2\theta ...$ to $cos (60+ \theta)=0$

Comment: @user474243 I added something, See now.

Answer (score 0):

use $$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$ and $$\cos(3x)=\cos(x)^3-3\cos(x)\sin(x)^2$$ and $$\sin(x)=2\,{\frac {\tan \left( x/2 \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$ and $$\cos(x)={\frac {1- \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{1+ \left( 
\tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$
additionally i have found that your equation can be written as $$2 \cos \left(x+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)-2 \sin (5 x)=0$$

Comment: how did you get the cos 3x identity?

Comment: and then on both the sides there will be different ratios, what to  do then?

Comment: a complete solution would be more helpful. Please

Comment: How can it be written like that?

Comment: $$\cos(2x+x)=\cos(2x)\cos(x)-\sin(2x)\sin(x)$$

Comment: $$\cos(2x)=\cos(x)^2-\sin(x)^2$$